# How to repeatedly update an instance variable as from `MouseEvent` javafx?

Tags: design-patterns, javafx, observer-pattern, eventhandler

I am using the Observer patter, and i would like to be able to update all observers that the xValue of the subject class has change, using the xValue from the `MouseEvent` so basically when the user clicks on the `scene`the `xComp`changes and the observer, or in this case the `Receiver`notices the change and does something depending on the change. I can add the code for the  observers if needed. Thank you for your time.

```
package subject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import //all things needed
import observer.Observer;

public class Sender extends Application implements Subject {
    private double xComp;
    private double yComp;

    private ArrayList<Observer> observers;
    //constructor
    public double getxComp() {
        return xComp;
    }

    //accessors
    public void setxComp(double xComp) {
        this.xComp = xComp;
    }

    public double getyComp() {
        return yComp;
    }
    public void setxyComp(double xComp, double yComp) {
        this.yComp = yComp;
        this.xComp=xComp;
    }
    public void setyComp(double yComp) {
        this.yComp = yComp;
    }

    public Sender() {
        observers= new ArrayList<Observer>();
    }

    @Override
    public void addObserver(Observer o) {
        observers.add(o);

    }

    @Override
    public void removeObserver(Observer o) {
        int index= observers.indexOf(o);
        observers.remove(index);

    }
    @Override
    public void notifyObserver() {
        for (Observer o: observers)
            o.update(this.getxComp(), this.getyComp());
    }
    //GUI
        public void start(Stage s) throws Exception {

            TextField tf = new TextField("no");
            Group root =new Group();
            root.getChildren().add(tf);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500,500);
            scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler <MouseEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                    Here

                }

            });
            s.setScene(scene);
            s.show();



        }

}
```

Comment: Update the value and notify the observers - done... Or simply use a [one of the properties in the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/package-summary.html) instead of your own implementation.

Comment: @fabian ive already done that, the notifying observers part but some reasons it wont be notify them, the observer arraylist get garbagecollected as soon as the `launch(args)`is invoked, and so it wont update because i tried  `System.out.println(observers.isEmplty)`and it printed `true` which suggested to me that my observer list is getting garbage collected

Comment: Do you create the `Sender` instance yourself and register the observers to that instance perhaps? `Application.launch` creates the instance of the `Application` subclass that is used itself, which may cause unexpected behaviour.